# Nginx can't send request to asp.net core 8 app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nginx, .net-8.0

I have a small ASP.NET core application that is running in Ubuntu with the help of nginx. It worked fine in .net 6 and .net 7. However, recently, I updated it to .net 8, and it stopped working. The app is starting fine from the docker image, but nginx can't send the request to it. I have the following errors in nginx logs:

```
2023/12/29 00:17:51 [error] 802461#802461: *19704 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 79.117.186.27, server: <myhost.com>, request: "GET /api/mygetmethod HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/mygetmethod", host: "<myhost.com>"
2023/12/29 00:18:41 [error] 802461#802461: *19704 recv() failed (104: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream, client: 79.117.186.27, server: <myhost.com>, request: "GET /api/mygetmethod HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/mygetmethod", host: "<myhost.com>"
```

I changed nothing except upgrading .net to the latest version.
All configs were set up according to the official Microsoft [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=linux-ubuntu).
What could I miss?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77729400/2501279) answer. Maybe it will help you. Other than that without [mre] we can only guess.

Comment: This is it! I was not aware of the default port changes. Thank you so much!